# Using a Subject to trigger a music list to reload

Tags: java, android, rx-java

In my Android app I have a Service that is periodically polling a server for a music playlist XML. For certain occasions I also want to trigger a reload manually.

I am using Retrofit for the server communication and my Service exposes an `Observable<Playlist>` to which some other components of the app can subscribe. At the moment there are two such subscribers: One Fragment that contains the playback controls and one other Service that manages the actual audio streaming as well as the updates to the Notifications.

Now, I want all Subscribers to receive any new playlist info as soon as it becomes available. In particular this means that if I trigger a reload manually from the Fragment, the Service should also immediately receive the server response.

No matter how I turn it, all my solutions need a Subject. Here's the one I like best:

```
private Observable<MusicInfoResponse> mReloadingObservable;
private PublishSubject<Long> mManualRefreshesSubject = PublishSubject.<Long>create();

private void setupObservable() {

    Observable<Long> timer = Observable.timer(0, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Observable<Long> pulses = Observable.merge(timer, mManualRefreshesSubject);

    mReloadingObservable = pulses
        .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<MusicInfoResponse>>() {

            @Override
            public Observable<MusicInfoResponse> call(Long aLong) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "reloading music info XML");
                return reloadMusicInfo();
            }
        })
        .share();
}

public Observable<MusicInfoResponse> subscribeToMusicInfo() {
    return mReloadingObservable;
}

public void triggerManualRefresh() {
    mManualRefreshesSubject.onNext(1l);
}
```

Since, it seems to me, one should generally avoid Subjects and try to use only normal Observables instead my question is: Is there any way to this that does not need Subjects? Is this a case where using Subjects is the way to go?

And also: What are the main drawbacks of Subjects in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no rule like

> one should generally avoid Subjects

You should just be careful around them, like you have. Just as a rule of thumb, keep Subjects private (inside your class), and if you want the outside world to be able to subscribe to it, just call `subject.asObservable`.

As for your code, you can perform the `setupObservable()` inside an `obervable.onSubscribe()` so that you have a cold observable and not a hot one.

If you really **have to** remove the `Subject`, you can do a `Observable.create(subsriber -> ...)`. This `subscriber` variable would be the replacement for your `mManualRefreshesSubject`.

Frankly, there is not much difference between either pattern. The only thing you should do is check whether the `subject.isUnsubscribed()` / `subscriber.isSubscribed`. One benifit of using a subscriber is that you make sure to do stuff `onSubscribe` and not before.

Comment: It just no occurred to me that I'd never accepted this answer until now... Sorry!